# Facebook like button changes to a "confirm" button and jumps to the left when clicked

Tags: html, facebook, button, facebook-like, xfbml

I've embedded a facebook like button on our page http://makethecitysoundbetter.com
When i click it, it turns into a "confirm" button, and moves to the left. When i click the "confirm" i get the normal share box, and after that i works as it should.

I have copied the instructions exactly from facebook's Like button page: developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

And i've even created an empty html page ONLY with facebooks code, copy pasted and placed exactly as they've written (http://makethecitysoundbetter.com/fb_test.html).

I've tried both the HTML5 and XFBML code, both with the same results..

Does anyone know what is going on, and how i can fix this?

It's very important that our share function works!

Thanks in advance!

Andy

Comment: Facebook places the “confirm” step into the like button flow, if there has been “suspicious” like activity going on (f.e. multiple likes/dislikes during testing). After the target will receive a certain amount of likes that look “normal”, the confirmation requirement will be switched off again. In the meantime, there is nothing you can do about it (and trying to “force” more likes to make it disappear quicker might actually backfire).

Comment: wow! thanks for the reply. Definitely hadn't seen that one coming!
This confirm step, is it as i've described? Did you look at the link? Just can't believe how clumpsy it is...

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. I ended up using the iframe version of the like button and now everything works great.